# Story about a teen girl who falls in love with an alien boy (or vice versa) whom she first sees naked in the woods

Tags: story-identification

A few years ago (not in the last two years but after 2010) I read a young adult science fiction romance in which a human girl falls in love with an alien humanoid boy.

The part I remember most vividly is in the beginning, where the girl sees the boy arrive naked in the forest (although in my memory it is the boy who sees the girl). If I am remembering correctly, one of them is across a river or creek from the other, and remains unseen.

Later the same person sees the other (in school?) and recognized him (or her). I believe the novel was made into a movie or tv show, but I may be confusing the book I read with a similar story.

The important part I'm after is the beginning in the forest. I thought the title was *Star Crossed* or something like that, but I guess not.

---

After some research, I suspect that the book is *[Obsidian](http://lux-series.wikia.com/wiki/Obsidian)* by Jennifer L. Armentrout, but I cannot find a preview that goes far enough into the book to show the forest scene.

Comment: Is is not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyle_XY

Comment: How many years is a few years? Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details

Comment: Thanks, @Edlothiad, I read that guide and did my best. "A few" means anywhere from two to five (cf. https://xkcd.com/1070/).

Comment: There's always a relevant XKCD. I only ask because sometimes people say a few and end up saying something like 5-10 years. Or they forget we're already in 2017 and say 2002! Thanks for looking at the guide. We probably have enough info for someone to ID it from those details as they seem unique enough.

Comment: You are right, of course, and "few" can mean different things. I made the time frame more clear (and hope I don't misremember when I read it). Thanks for your help, @Edlothiad.

Comment: No problem, it’s what I’m here for!

Comment: Check up the novella "The Lightning Tree" by Patrick Rothfuss. The novella was first published in the anthology Rogues on June 17, 2014 . It has the scene very similar to the one you describe Link here. http://softandonly.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Rothfuss-Patrick-Kingkiller-Chronicle-The-0.25-The-Lightning-Tree.pdf

Comment: @user14111 According to the OED, *few* (without article) is opposed to *many* and means "a small number" (the exact size of which will depend on the context), while *a few* (with article, as in your boldface example) is opposed to *none* and can mean any number including large numbers (e.g. "quite a few").

Comment: A *few* is 2-5, indeed, but *several* is 3-7. Somebody is wrong on the internet!

Answer (score 3):

Was it written from the boy's Point of View or girl's? Because if it is written from the boy's point of view, that sounds to me like the novella "The Lightning Tree" by Patrick Rothfuss. The novella was first published in the anthology Rogues on June 17, 2014 . It has the scene very similar to the one you describe (a girl looking at the boy while he bathes. He does the same to her later). There is some love after he does that.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the one. The story I read was definitely a YA novel, not an adult fantasy novella.

Comment: Story or a novel? Did you ever read The Nation by Terry Pratchett? It is the novel and has the similar scene too, but no school. It seems like this trope is more prevalent than I thought.

Comment: I guess it is somewhat common. I thought it was original when I saw it in Time Traveler's Wife.